# $G$ group, $H \triangleleft G$ such that $\frac{G}{H}$ is cyclic, $H$ is residually finite and $H$ is finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group with a normal subgroup $H \triangleleft G$ such that $\frac{G}{H}$ is cyclic, $H$ is residually finite and $H$ is finitely generated. Show that $G$ is residually finite.

A group $H$ being residually finite means for all $h \in H$ there exists $N \triangleleft H$
such that $[H,N] < \infty$ and $h \notin N$.

---

So, i've been working on this forever, I think i'm on the right track but could definitely use some help finishing it up and smoothing out some details.

Let $g \in G$. Then, since $\frac{G}{H}$ is cyclic, $g = z^rh$ for some $z \in G$ and $h \in H$. Since $H$ is residually finite, $\exists$ $N \triangleleft H$ such that $h \notin N$ and $[H,N]=n < \infty$. Since $H$ is finitely generated, it has finitely many subgroups of index $n$. Since $H \triangleleft G$, we have that $N^{z^r} \triangleleft H^{z^r} = H$ for all $r \in \mathbb{N}$; thus $N$ has only finitely many conjugates in $G$. Let $I$ be the intersection of all these conjugates of $N$. Then $[H,I] < \infty$ and $I$ char $H$, and so $I \triangleleft G$

edit: STill trying to finish the proof!!

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78341/residually-finite-by-mathbbz-groups-are-residually-finite

Comment: In Andreas' answer to the linked question, $Hu^{m\mathbb{Z}}$ is the set $\{hu^{mi}\mid h\in H, i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. By the conditions set up there, this is a normal subgroup, and has finite index in $G$. Given any element $g\in G$, the subgroup $H$ and the integer $m$ can be picked so that $g\not\in Hu^{m\mathbb{Z}}$, and the result follows.

Comment: Sorry... I'm a bit slow. Can you explain why it $Hu^{m \mathbb{Z}}$ is of finite index in $G$?

Comment: Cosets are $hu^jHu^{m\mathbb{Z}}$ where $hH$ are cosets of $N/H$ and $0\leq j<m$.

Comment: Would it make more sense to write $u^jhHu^{m \mathbb{Z}}$?? Or why in this circumstance does it not matter to write $hu^j$ instead of $u^jh$?

Comment: It is easier to see if you write $hu^j$, as two cosets are equal if $(h_1u^{j_1})^{-1}h_2u^{j_2}\in H$, but then $h_1^{-1}h_2\in H$ and $H$ is $u$-invariant.

Comment: $H$ is u-invariant under conjugation ?? Or do u mean that $u^jH = H$ ??

Comment: This is in Andreas' answer: $uHu^{-1}=H=u^{-1}Hu$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $H$ is residually finite is not needed. If $G/H$ is generated by $zH$  then $G$ is generated by $z$ and generators of $H$.

The assumption that $H$ is residually finite implies that $G$ is also residually finite. Since that was the real question the proof is this. If the cyclic factor group is finite then $H$ has finite index in $G$ and so $G$ is residually finite (because every subgroup of finite index of $H$ contains a characteristic subgroup of finite index).
If the cyclic factor group is infinite then we have an extension of a finitely generated subgroup by a free group which is residually finite (proved by Baumslag): this extension necessarily splits and a semidirect product of two residually finite finitely generated groups is residually finite.

An alternative proof. Every finite index subgroup of $H$ contains a finite index characteristic subgroup. So $G$ is residually an extension of  a finite group by a cyclic group. It remains to show that an extension $G$ of a finite group $N$ by a cyclic group is residually finite. But in this group the derived subgroup is inside $N$ so it is finite. Then the center is of finite index. A finitely generated Abelian group is residually finite and we are done.

Comment: ugh, typed question wrong. meant to say show $G$ is resid finite.

Comment: You are so close to a green check mark my man!!! Why do you keep calling $N$ a finite group? I thought all we know is that it's finite index in the finitely generated group $H$... does that imply that it is finite??

Comment: Both proofs are correct.

Comment: I belive you, but when you say $N$ is a finite group, do you mean that $N$ has finitely many elements? Or that it's finite index??

Comment: Finite groups have finitely many elements.

Comment: When we quotient by the characteristic subgroup of finite index of a group with cyclic quotient that subgroup becomes finite.

Comment: That is the $N$ in my answer.